Understanding this LLM example from Sebastian LLM book and how can I improve the results of the text generation
I have this file in github based on the book by Sebastian Raschka
The full code is here
https://github.com/berlinbrown/berlin-learn-ml-dl-capstone-projects/blob/main/basic-exercises/basic-llm/more-full-run-llm.py
I made modifications and trying to destruct the approach.  I just had two main questions.  I am not understanding at what point the LLM data gets downloaded and pulled into memory.  I can see where I connect hugging face listed in the code below.  I thought I would get gigs of data and not seeing that.  How much from this example of model data is loaded into memory.
For example, here is the download part:
tokenizer_file = hf_hub_download(
    repo_id="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b",
    filename="tokenizer.model",
    local_dir="Llama-2-7B"
)

It could be because I trimmed down the parameters:
LLAMA2_CONFIG_7B = {
    "vocab_size": 32000,      # Keeping the same vocabulary size
    "context_length": 4096,   # Keeping the same context length
    "emb_dim": 1280,          # Reduced embedding dimension (approximately 10% of original 4096)
    "n_heads": 4,             # Reduced number of attention heads (10% of original 32)
    "n_layers": 4,            # Reduced number of layers (10% of original 32)
    "hidden_dim": 1100,       # Reduced intermediate dimension in FeedForward (10% of original 11008)
    "dtype": torch.bfloat16   # Keeping lower-precision dtype to save memory
}

...
When I run the example,
token_ids = generate(
    model=model,
    idx=text_to_token_ids("Every effort moves", tokenizer).to(device),
    max_new_tokens=30,
    context_size=LLAMA2_CONFIG_7B["context_length"],
    top_k=1,
    temperature=0.
)

I kind of only get gibberish, how can I improve the expected output.
Output text:
Every effort moves Costa Deep };UCvicelink indicatedbertoesti Посиланняüssen Jason impliesição следúesia француз responseUI westdescagerayaходитственный externs notify января relationship
Also curious how the russian got in there?
